# Displaying buttons with collapsible content in rows using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, less

I have the following simplified html

```
<div class="package-attributes ">
<div class="container-package">
    <div class="container-button">
        <button type="button" class="ant-btn">
            <span>PackageContents</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div>
    <div class="ant-row">
        My content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-package">
    <div class="container-button">
        <button type="button" class="ant-btn">
            <span>PackageContents</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div>
</div>
<div class="container-package">
    <div class="container-button">
        <button type="button" class="ant-btn">
            <span>PackageContents</span>
        </button>
    </div>
<div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a set of buttons that are all displayed in a row side by side.
But when a button is clicked, an additional element is rendered with content. In the above code, the first button has been clicked, and the `ant-row` element has been added.
When a button has been opened like this, I want the `ant-row` contents to fill the entire row, and the other buttons be pushed up or down to another row.

This is how it looks *currently* when I add `disply:flex` to `package-attributes`, with the top being no button opened, and the bottom being a button open.
[image: before]

And this is how it *should* look
[image: after]